# kubectl kudo plugin not working after install using brew in linux?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have installed the kudo plugin on my Linux machine following the instructions in the [Kudo CLI](https://kudo.dev/docs/cli.html#setup-the-kudo-kubectl-plugin) page using brew. But it throws error on execution,

```
user@factotum:~$ kubectl kudo
Error: unknown command "kudo" for "kubectl"
Run 'kubectl --help' for usage.
```

I tried to list the available plugins, but doesn't have any,

```
user@factotum:~$ kubectl plugin list
error: unable to find any kubectl plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

Just installed to reproduce and seems works fine. Have you init it with `kubectl kudo init` as it mentioned in [Install KUDO into your cluster](https://kudo.dev/docs/#install-kudo-into-your-cluster)?

My steps(Ubuntu 16.04, 4.15.0-1033-gcp):

```
$sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper
$brew update
$brew vendor-install ruby
$brew update

==> Migrating from Linuxbrew/brew to Homebrew/brew
  Linuxbrew/brew has been merged into Homebrew/brew!
  Linuxbrew/brew will no longer be updated.
  Your git remote has been changed from
     https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew.git
  to https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
  See the blog post at https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/

Already up-to-date.

$brew tap kudobuilder/tap

brew install kudo-cli
==> Downloading https://linuxbrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable-ruby/portable-ruby-2.6.3.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
....
....
....
....
  /home/bla/.linuxbrew/Cellar/kudo-cli/0.10.1: 5 files, 38.2MB, built in 6 seconds
==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
==> Caveats
==> kubernetes-cli
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /home/bla/.linuxbrew/etc/bash_completion.d


$ kubectl kudo init
$KUDO_HOME has been configured at /home/bla/.kudo
✅ installed crds
✅ installed service accounts and other requirements for controller to run
✅ installed kudo controller
```

Test:

```
$ kubectl kudo get instances
List of current installed instances in namespace "default":
.

$ kubectl kudo install redis
operator.kudo.dev/v1beta1/redis created
operatorversion.kudo.dev/v1beta1/redis-0.2.0 created
instance.kudo.dev/v1beta1/redis-instance created

$ kubectl plugin list
The following compatible plugins are available:
/home/bla/.linuxbrew/bin/kubectl-kudo
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the issue was not with the init part. I cant even make the `kubectl kudo` to work. Seems the installed plugin was not able to detect by the kubectl client.

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute `kubectl-kudo`? A kubectl plugin is basically just a binary that starts with `kubectl-`.

So, check where brew installed the kudo binary and check your $PATH.

And you can use `kubectl-kudo` instead of `kubectl kudo` if the plugin mechanism doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add the `brew` environment variables to your shell?

As pr https://brew.sh/ and their install-script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh you need to add brew to your PATH among others.

OP is tagging `bash` here so adding this to your shell configuration file.
There will be slight variations based on what shell the user is running, `bash`, `ksh`, `csh`, `tcsh`.

```sh
# At the bottom of .bashrc or .bash_profile
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```